# Makefile pass define at compile time?

Tags: compilation, makefile, linux-kernel, kernel-module, kbuild

I am trying to pass a "define variable called DEBUG" at compile time for a kernel module.

i.e provide the same functionality as DEBUG does below, but in a Makefile for a kernel module.

```
gcc -o foo -DDEBUG=1 foo.c
```

Can anyone give me a hint on how this can be achieved?

The Makefile:

```
# name of the module to be built
TARGET ?= test_module

# How to pass this during compile time? (-D$(DEBUG) or something similar)
DEBUG ?= 1              

#define sources
SRCS := src/hello.c

#extract required object files
OBJ_SRCS :=  $(SRCS:.c=.o)

#define path to include directory containing header files
INCLUDE_DIRS = -I$(src)/includes 
ccflags-y := $(INCLUDE_DIRS)

#define the name of the module and the source files
obj-m += $(TARGET).o
$(TARGET)-y := $(OBJ_SRCS)

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
    @echo "insert module:\n\t sudo insmod $(TARGET).ko"
    @echo "remove module:\n\t sudo rmmod $(TARGET)"

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

I am using the module from [link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/07/write-linux-kernel-module/) (with a small change in the init function, see the #if #endif statement)

hello.c:

```
#include <linux/module.h>    // included for all kernel modules
#include <linux/kernel.h>    // included for KERN_INFO
#include <linux/init.h>      // included for __init and __exit macros

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Lakshmanan");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A Simple Hello World module");

static int __init hello_init(void)
{
    #if (DEBUG == 1)
    printk(KERN_INFO "DEBUG = 1\n")
    #endif 
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world!\n");
    return 0;    // Non-zero return means that the module couldn't be loaded.
}

static void __exit hello_cleanup(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Cleaning up module.\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_cleanup);
```

I would like to see that dmesg poduces the following after

sudo insmod test_module.ko

```
DEBUG = 1
Hello world!
```

**Solution:**

```
ccflags-y := -DDEBUG=$(DEBUG)
```

Made the code below execute as intended

```
#if (DEBUG == 1)
printk(KERN_INFO "DEBUG = 1\n")
#endif
```

Comment: `ccflags-y := $(INCLUDE_DIRS) -DDEBUG` perhaps?

Comment: Never ever write `make` directly in any recipe.  Always use the variable `$(MAKE)` to run a sub-make.

Comment: Btw, in the example above usage of compile time insertion is a non-optimal. I recommend to look at how dynamic debug is implemented (in a part of storage the code and stuff).

Answer (score 0):

```
ccflags-y := -DDEBUG=$(DEBUG)
```

Made the code below execute as intended

```
#if (DEBUG == 1)
printk(KERN_INFO "DEBUG = 1\n")
#endif
```